# Cocoa get string width in pixels from font

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fonts

I am trying to find the width in pixels of a string from the font and font size. I am currently using this code, but it is not working 100% of the time. Is there another way to do it?

```
NSSize textSize = [aTextLayer.string sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bank Gothic Medium", NSFontNameAttribute, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:aTextLayer.fontSize], NSFontSizeAttribute, nil]];
```

Comment: I think there are methods for that in `NSAttributedString(AppKitAdditions)`.

Comment: There is no “width in pixels”. Pixels only make sense in a raster environment, such as a window or bitmap context, and those pixels only change when you draw a vector into the context, such as by drawing a string. Measuring a string returns its width (and height) in *points*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSAttributedString` is granted a `-size` method by the Application Kit Additions.

```
NSDictionary* attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"Bank Gothic Medium", NSFontNameAttribute,
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:aTextLayer.fontSize], NSFontSizeAttribute,
    nil];
NSAttributedString* attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:aTextLayer.string attributes:attributes];
NSSize size = attributedString.size;
```

Comment: That didn't fix it. It's still not changing. The fontSize will change from 10 to 22, but the size is still the same...

Answer (score 4):

Here is what i use to get the size of a string...

```
NSSize size = [@"Some text" sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:24.0f] forKey:NSFontAttributeName]];
```

**NOTE:** If you are adding the string to a textfield, i have found that you need to add about 10 to size.width for it to fit.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the actual `NSFont` (or `UIFont`) object instead of just the name of the font.

Comment: Documentation says `NSFontNameAttribute` is "An optional `NSString` object that specifies the font name."

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  This is actually going to fix some other problems we had as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another example:

```
NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%u:%u:%u.000", hours, minutes, seconds];
NSSize boundingSize = {100,300};  //I suppose this is the constraints?
NSRect boundingRect = [test boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize options:NULL attributes:stringAttributes];
point.x -= boundingRect.size.width; //This point points at the end of screen
[test drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:stringAttributes];
```

Here is for the stringAttributes, that may help noobs like me:

```
NSMutableDictionary *stringAttributes;
    stringAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [stringAttributes setObject:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Monaco" size:16] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [stringAttributes setObject:[NSColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    [stringAttributes setObject:[NSColor blackColor] forKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];
```